# replacing a 4 way switch with wifi switch

Tags: wifi

I have a basement hallway with a 4 way light switch configuration as follows:

- 3 switches
- 2 lights

Trying to replace one of the switches with a gosuna wifi light switch, but can't seem to figure out which one to replace (doesn't matter) and the wiring. In addition to them ALL having green (ground) wires, here are the wire color configurations (& pics) of each one

- switch #1 = red, black, white
- switch #2 = red, black, white
- switch #3 = white, white, red, red

The gosund wifi switch has a white wire coming out of it along with 3 available "hole connectors" for wires labeled "traveler1, Live, traveler2"

I tried replacing switch #1 with the GoSund. The hallway lights worked, but only with switches #2 & 3. The GoSund wifi switch didn't work at all.

Any ideas which switch I should replace and the wiring?

Here are the pics

Gosund Wifi Switch:
[image: GoSund Wifi Switch]

Switch #1 (red, black, white)
[image: switch #1]

Switch #2 (red, black, white)
[image: Switch #2]

Switch #3 (white white, red, red)
[image: Switch #3]

Comment: Are you locked into the Gosund switches, or are you willing to consider a different option?  Also, can you post photos looking into the back of box #3?

Comment: The black-white-red in switch 1 and 2, are they all in the same cable?

Answer (score 1):

The black wire in *either* Switch #1 or Switch #2 will be live power.  You have to replace *that* switch with your wifi one.   The black wire in the other of those two switches will go to the lights.  Determine which switch has live power and replace that one.

There must be two cables entering each box, with various combinations of wires.  Your photos show what wires are actually connected to the respective switches, but those wires come in each case from more than one cable and you need to consider  how the cables and other wires are configured.

Here's is what you probably need to do.  Let's imagine Switch #1 has the live.  From the live cable, probably black/white, the black goes to your new switch "live", the white to your new switch "neutral".  From the other cable, probably red/black/white, the red and black go to the traveller terminals (either way) and the white ALSO goes to the neutral terminal.  All the grounds (green/copper) get joined together.

That should work.

If you add info about the cable configuration and all the wire colors, this answer can be more precise.

Comment: Your WiFi switch is a three way, it will not replace a four way. You will either get a different WiFi switch or replace one of the three way switches. Pick the one that has the power feed.